# How to filter 4 numbers in column

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to filter 2 numbers like less than 25 and greater than 50 and so on, But I'm wondering how to filter 4 numbers like between 250 and 290  or if it is between 70 and 110.

The codes I have tried so far are

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$AK$18").AutoFilter Field:=26, _
    Criteria1:=">=70", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=110"

ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$AK$18").AutoFilter Field:=26, _
    Criteria1:=">=250", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=290"
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$AK$18").AutoFilter Field:=26, _
    Criteria1:=Array(">70", "<110", ">250", "<290"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$AK$18").AutoFilter Field:=25, _
    Criteria1:=">=70", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=110", Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:=">=250", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=290"
```

None of these work can so im wondering if what im trying to do is possible.

Comment: How about having an auxiliary column with the logic for filtering returning, say, `0` and `1` and filtering on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean write a loop and in a seperate column write a 0 and 1 and filter that column for the 1s?

Comment: no put a formula in a helper column that returns 1 if the numbers are in one of the ranges and 0 if not.  Then filter on 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an **Advanced Filter** for what you are trying to achieve. Here is how to apply:

```
Range("A5:C10").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range _
    ("A1:D2"), Unique:=False
```

1. Make sure your data has column headers.
2. You need to create a **Criteria Section** above your main data. To do this, insert at least 3 blank rows above your data. First one is for the headers, second one will get criteria; third one is required to be blank (to separate main data and criteria section. See the image below.
3. Copy/paste column titles from your main data to the newly created first row (see image below).
4. Starting from the second row, provide your criteria. Each criterion row will be "OR"ed with the other criteria rows. If you need to "AND" them, use single row.
5. If you need to "AND" two or more conditions on a single column, create new columns in the criteria range with the same title. For example, I wanted to add two conditions on **Sales** column in the image below, so I added two **Sales** columns (C and D) in the criteria range.
6. Provide your conditions using standard operators.
7. Now choose **Advanced Filter** dialog from **Data** tab in the main Ribbon. Select your data range (A5:C10 in my example), criteria range (A1:D2 in my example) and click OK. Make sure you do not include blank row when selecting criteria range.

See [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-4c9222fe-8529-4cd7-a898-3f16abdff32b) for more examples.

[image]